# how to convert multiple student enrollments to column by using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-query-store

I have an `enrollment` table like one student enrolled in multiple courses.

[image]

How can I convert courses in previous image into columns?

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information to. your question as editable text. Provide the table definition, some sample data and the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
name,
email,
(case when course = 'course1' then course1 end) as course1,
(case when course = 'course2' then course2 end) as course2,
(case when course = 'course3' then course3 end) as course3
from enrollment
group by name, email
```